# How to make dynamic navigation for ul and li using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to do dynamic navigation using ul and li. But i am not able to do for sub menu navigation, i am able to display parent menu only. I am using hashmap by using string and list as key value pairs.

Here's my code implemented

In angularjs script code:

```
$scope.listMap = [{'key':'Parent Menu', 'values':objectList}];

<div ng-repeat="(key,values) in listMap">
     <ul>
         <li>{{key}}
             <div ng-repeat="value in values">
                 <ul>
                    <li>{{value.object.name}}</li>
                 <ul>
             </div>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

It displays only parent menu but sub menu is not displaying, that i need another that if any of the parent menu that doesn't have sub menu i need to check that one in order to avoid running ul inside the main ul.

Can you please help me to proceed or share any examples for dynamic menus for navigation using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below. It is totally possible to do it. You just need to improve the structure of the data.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.listMap = [{
    name: 'Home',
    value: [{
      name: 'File'
    }, {
      name: 'Items'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Second Menu',
    value: [{
      name: 'Nothings'
    }, {
      name: 'Ooo LA LA'
    }]
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <div ng-repeat="item in listMap">
    <ul>
      <li>{{item.name}}
        <div ng-repeat="value in item.value">
          <ul>
            <li>{{value.name}}</li>
            <ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```